# How to reduce line spacing below 1.0 in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, line-spacing

I'm trying to get a document on a single page.

There is too much whitespace between the lines.

I attempt to reduce it with:

```
[Select all text] -> Format -> Paragraph -> Indents & Spacing -> Line Spacing: Multiple -> At: 0.7
```

However this has no effect. Is this a bug? Is there any way to fix it? It seems inconceivable that there might be no solution.

Comment: There is a function in word, which can reduce the number of pages. However it is not included in the ribbons. So you can go to "options", "change ribbons" and search for "reduce pages". (Sorry, I don't know the correct english names, as I have a localized version.)

Comment: Decreasing line spacing below 1 means that lines overlap and part of the letters won't be visible. You may try to decrease spacing above / below paragraphs and margins. and if that doesn't help, then play around at character level: spacing, font size, font type.